# Redirect URL while persisting starting URL in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-lambda-edge

I have have the following ask:

There is an existing application that has the url for **mysite.com**

Users can come from different domains:

**example.com** or
**example1.com**

etc.

I need to redirect users to **mysite.com** from **example.com** or **example1.com**. They key part the originating url MUST persist.

So if i am a user and coming from **example.com** - i should see **exmaple.com** while i am on **mysite.com.**

mysite.com is part of the aws serverless stack - using AWS Lambda, AWS API Gateway, and S3

Comment: When you want to redirect user to mysite.com? on a button click?

Comment: user hitting example.com

Comment: If the original URL remains in the browser's address bar, then you are attempting something that (I would argue) is not properly called a *redirect*.  It's proxying or masking with iframes or something else, but to get you where you need to go, I'd suggest we need a more thorough description of your scenario before any quality answers can be forthcoming, including who controls `example.com` -- you or a 3rd party or perhaps you are referring to accessing your various resources in `*.amazonaws.com` under a common domain that you control.  Each has a different answer.

Comment: You mean when user hits `example.com` you want user to redirect automatically to `mysite.com`? Can you provide bit more details of the use case?

Comment: thanks everyone but figured it out.